# Understanding LifeCycle of hapi js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

```
  register: async (server, options) => {

        server.ext('onRequest', (request, h) => {
            if (request.params) {
                log.verbose(`onRequest:${request.method.toUpperCase()}:${request.path}/${request.params}`)
            } else {
                log.verbose(`onRequest:${request.method.toUpperCase()}:${request.path}`)
            }

            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(request.query).length) {
                log.verbose(`onRequest:queryParameters: ${JSON.stringify(request.query)}`)
            }

            if (request.headers && request.headers['x-access-token']) {
                log.verbose(`onRequest:heders:x-access-token ${JSON.stringify(request.headers['x-access-token'])}`)
            }

            return h.continue
        })

        server.ext('onPreAuth', (request, h) => {
            log.verbose('onPreAuth')
            return h.continue
        })

        server.ext('onCredentials', (request, h) => {
            log.verbose('onCredentials')
            return h.continue
        })

        server.ext('onPostAuth', (request, h, error) => {
            if (request.payload) {
                log.verbose(`onPostAuth:bodyPayload: ${JSON.stringify(request.payload)}`)
            }
            return h.continue
        })

        server.ext('onPreHandler', (request, h) => {
            log.verbose('onPreHandler')
            return h.continue
        })

        server.ext('onPostHandler', (request, h) => {
            log.verbose('onPostHandler')
            return h.continue
        })

        server.ext('onPreResponse', (request, h) => {
            if (request && request.response && request.response.source) {
                try {
                    log.verbose(`onPreResponse:${JSON.stringify(request.response.source)}`)
                } catch (err) {
                    log.warn(err)
                    log.verbose(h.request.response.source.toString())
                }
            }
            return h.continue
        })
    }
```

These are Hapi LifeCycle:

1. OnRequest: Called when request comes to server.
2. OnPreAuth: called when request comes to auth part of route.
3. OnPostAuth: called when request goes out from auth part of route.
4. OnPreHandler: called when request comes to handler part of route.
5. OnPostHandler: called when request goes out from Handler part of route.
6. OnPreResponse: called when returning response back.

   7 *onCredentials*:  is new to Hapi v17.

   Not able to understand for what purpose *onCredentials* is used for.
   Also, correct me if i am understanding wrong the life cycle of hapi.

Comment: Can someone with 2.5k+ points set those 2 tags as synonyms : `hapijs` and `hapi.js` ? They seem to be about the same API (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hapi.js/synonyms)

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding is correct. *onCredentials* added to between *OnPreAuth* and *OnPostAuth*, here is little information about it.

> A new onCredentials extension point and the ability to change the
>   request credentials before authorization is validated.

source: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3658

Here is little more

> onCredentials: a new Request Extension Point Each request served with
>   hapi follows a predefined path: the request lifecycle. Depending on
>   whether you need authentication or validation, the framework skips
>   individual lifecycle points.
>
> There’s a new extension point in hapi v17: onCredentials. This
>   extension point locates after onPreAuth and before onPostAuth. In
>   onPreAuth, hapi authenticates the request and identifies the user. The
>   authorization is part of onPostAuth, like checking the request scope
>   to verify that the request has access rights.
>
> In onCredentials, you can customize the credentials before the request
>   authorization.

source: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-v17-upgrade-guide-your-move-to-async-await

That means you can modify credentials object. Here is simple sample code. Let's say you want to update credentials scope after authentication based on user information.

```
server.ext('onCredentials', (request, h) => {

    request.auth.credentials.scope = 'customadmin';
    return h.continue;
});
```

[Hapi.js Scope Explanation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-restrict-user-access-with-scopes)